# How do I obtain the operating point of a particular cell at module open-circuit in pvmismatch?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pvmismatch to calculate the power dissipated in a shaded cell within a partially shaded 144 half-cell module. See a working example below, based on examples I found in previous pvmismatch issues on github.

Setting up the module with partial shading (cell 0 is set to receive 50% irradiance) works fine. Now I need to determine the operating point of the shaded cell when the module is at short-circuit. It would be good to have the same information for when the module is at MPP, too.

Is anyone able to direct me as to how to do this?

```
import numpy as np
from pvmismatch.pvmismatch_lib import (pvcell, pvconstants, pvmodule,
                                       pvstring, pvsystem)
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

v_bypass = np.float64(-0.3)  # [V] trigger voltage of bypass diode
cell_area = np.float64(252/2)

halfcell144_bypass3 = pvmodule.crosstied_cellpos_pat([24, 24, 24], 2, partial=True)

pv_mod = pvmodule.PVmodule(cell_pos = halfcell144_bypass3, pvcells = None, pvconst
                            = None, Vbypass = v_bypass, cellArea = cell_area)

pv_mod.setSuns([0.5], cells = [0])

f = pv_mod.plotMod()
```

Comment: For reference the half cell issue is here: https://github.com/SunPower/PVMismatch/issues/118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using [pvmismatch](https://sunpower.github.io/PVMismatch/)! To get the power dissipated in the shaded cell when the PV-module is at open circuit use the attributes `Vsubstr` & `Isubstr` to find the open circuit voltage of the PV-module substring by interpolating the IV curve where current is zero:

```
Voc_substr0 = np.interp(0.0, np.flip(pv_mod.Isubstr[0]), np.flip(pv_mod.Vsubstr[0]))  # flip so x increases monotonically
```

This is the voltage of the first substring, but the currents add up to zero. AFAIK there's no attributes that returns the current for each block in a partially tied PV-module, so we can add up those cells manually. It would be a nice PR, if you're interested.

```
Vblock = pv_mod.Vcell[0]
Iblock = pv_mod.Icell[0]
for idx in range (1, 24):  # first 24 cells
    Vblock += no.interp(Iblock, np.flip(pv_mod.Icell[idx]), np.flip(pv_mod.Vcell[idx]))  # flip so x increases
```

Now we have the IV curve of the 1st block in the 1st substring which includes the shaded cell. We know the open circuit voltage is `Voc_substr0`. Interpolate again to get the current of this block, which may be non-zero, so that the two blocks sum to zero.

```
Ioc_substr0 = np.interp(Voc_substr0, Vblock, Iblock)
```

Finally, all the cells in this block carry this current. Interpolate the cell power of the shaded cell

```
Pcell0 = np.interp(Ioc_substr0, np.flip(pv_mod.Icell[0]), np.flip(pv_mod.Pcell[0])
```

Does it work??? Anyway, to repeat with mpp, use `mpp_idx = np.argmax(pv_mod.Pmod)` to get the index closest to the max power of the module, then repeat everything above, except with a current of `pv_mod.Imod[mpp_idx]` instead of 0.0 ok?